# How to make the background image not interfere with text when the image has icons

Tags: android, android-listview

I currently have a very plain ListView with no background image and just text for each item in the list.

Some people have voiced the problem that it isn't intuitive to click on the list items.

So I am researching what kind of a background image to create so that it makes the list item look "very clickable"

One option is to have the background image contain those little icons on the right that look have something like a ">" and its a sign that it should be clicked on.

But I am wondering what if the text is long on the listitem and it will overlap over the ">" icon. How is that usually handled? Is there a way to make text only extend 90% of the entire listitem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and cleanest solution would be to make your `TextView` width `match_parent` and use the [`android:drawableRight`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableRight) attribute in your XML to specify the drawable that you want to be displayed on the right side of your text.

Comment: Thanks! I am thinking how that would work together.  The parent is the entire screen width, no? Who would be the parent in this case? Sorry little confused :)

Comment: The parent is the Listview. However wide the listview is, the textview would be this wide as well.

Comment: But still, if the text spans 100% of the width of the screen, won't the drawable_right just make it overlap the text on the right side of the screen?

Comment: The drawable is part of the TextView's foreground. It can't overlap multiple things on the foreground - the text will just wrap.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something like every item on list should be shown clickable, just do one thing, design a layout with text view and inflate that layout in your lsitview adapter class in getview method. and instead of return convertview, return your inflated view from there.